# Disable re-posting when user presses back button (data comes from URL parameters)

Tags: php

I get the stuff that has to be inserted into database via the URL parameters, unfortunately I can't change that at the moment. So it's something like this: send.php?id=2&messag=hello etc.

After the data is sent, I send the user using PHP's location to another page. If a user presses back button, the data ise being sent of course again, since the url containts still the same parameters. I also can't make self-rediraction because the data comes from GET url paremeters.

Unfortunately I also don't have access to the forms that the user is using to submit the info, to create a unique timestamp or something like this. What would be the best way in this scenario to avoid double submissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the GET to a POST which is highly recommended whenever a request causes something to change, I would recommend checking against duplicate entries on the backend.

It's up to you to determine what constitutes a duplicate: are all the parameters the same? is some key parameter is the same? or was the same query sent within the past 5 minutes from the same user?

Another solution would be to use a ["nonce"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). When the page is generated, send along a nonce -- a unique token that can only be used once. When they click "back" it will attempt send the same nonce, which you can check has already been used up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do more than checking the submission by storing something in the `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`.

You could put a timestamp and check against that for not allowing re-send in a time lapse of 10 mins for example.

The true is that it is bad programmed. Insert request must be by `POST`. That way the browser alone alerts you. And a redirection will work.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this is horrible design, but unfortunately right now I can't change it.